# Show Entries Based on Category - Localised Site

Tags: categories, localization

I have the following code to display entries based on a single category:

```
{# Identify the primary category you want #}
{% set cat = craft.categories.title('events').level(1).first() %}


{# Grab an array of entries related to the primary category #}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('projects').relatedTo(cat).find() %}

{% for entry in entries %}

<article class="">
  <h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>
  <h5 class="subtitle">{{ entry.subtitle }}</h5>
  <a href="{{ entry.url }}" class="button button--ujarak button--border-thin button--text-thick">Learn more</a><br>
  <hr class="rule rule--dashed">
</article>

{% endfor %}
```

This works fine for the home locale (en) but on the others it displays all entries regardless of whether the category has been applied to it or not.

Answer (score 1):

The slugs for the different locales were not the same. Changed those and all fixed.